# How do I get onbord WIFI to work on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: wireless

I have been trying to get Ubuntu Server to work with the built in WiFi on the motherboard with no luck.

I was trying to troubleshoot it with some forum posts and edited the interfaces file.

See below for the info requested from the sticky. I have since undone all the changes I made to the file but would still like to get the wifi working if possible.

Thank you!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Jun 2016 17:19 PDT -0700

Booted last: 23 Jun 2016 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

ubuntu (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1849:10a1]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 13d3:3393 IMC Networks 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

./wireless-info: line 192: rfkill: command not found

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 143360  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
ath3k                  20480  0
bluetooth             520192  6 ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211

##### interfaces ########################

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##Changed enp3s0 to wlp1s0 in two spots below

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.0.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
wpa-ssid 305Oak2
wpa-psk <WPA key removed>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.0.1

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2605:e000:8a49:a400:<IP6 'enp3s0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'enp3s0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:941715 (941.7 KB)  TX bytes:5680219 (5.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 209.18.47.62
nameserver 209.18.47.61
nameserver 8.8.8.8

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    None found.

Running:

    None found.

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

grep: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

No NetworkManager profiles found.

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F7E3AF932B15681132EA595
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     6FBD9F8A613FDFA282AB4FE
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     BF9F4930086BABAAF3CD9BA
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     3FCDBF7CE71CB8FB980D59D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     2B85DCB887D9376A61652DD
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.591931] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    3.591934] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    3.591937] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    3.591938] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    3.628884] ath9k 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.031680] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   31.032446] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
[   31.032647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```